# Detect table value change in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, profiler

Given the situation is as follows:

1. There is a black-box Java application (without source code, and obfuscated) connecting
   to a SQL Server.
2. The application is fully operational: user is able to insert, update, and delete records inside

I want to capture the operation-to-table-change, i.e., if an operation is done in the application, I want to know which field(s) are modified in that operation. Besides using profiler, any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You can try SQL Trace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL you would want to set up an audit configuration to log the necessary changes.  Auditing is fully configurable and for lack of event wanting to try and paraphrase it this is a pretty good article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx.  This is for 2008 but it would be setup the same way in 2008 R2 or 2012.  I can't say if/how it is possible on an older version of SQL server.